# Search remote page for a string

Tags: php, linux, url, wget

Is it possible to search a remote page with a given URL for a given string, and indicate whether it exists, and if so, some indication of where it was found?

For instance, "Post Your Question" is included on this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.

In addition to searching just the page given by the URL, I would also like to search any JS or CSS links.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried, what did you encounter, what are the problems?

Comment: Don't know where to start and haven't tried anything.  I am somewhat PHP competent, and thought of writing my own script but seems like a lot of work.  Also, I thought I recalled wget having this type of functionality, but wasn't sure and are looking into it.

Comment: Well, the question is a bit too generic. One of the approaches can be: load a page, look for a string in it, if found set a flag, parse out any CSS/JS links, load them (one by one, or in parallel) search there for a string, set flags for any matches, print out the results. There are really tons of possibilities, it all depends on your programming savviness ;)

Comment: Hoping for a firebug plugin!  No such luck :<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to traverse through the contents of an html file.

Doing something like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
$htmlstring = $html->plaintext;
if(strstr($htmlstring, 'Post Your Question') === true)
  // do your stuff here
```

Then to get the url to css or js:

```
foreach($html->find('link') as $css) {
  $cssHref = $css->href;
  //load the css, parse or whatever
}
foreach($html->find('script') as $script) {
  $jsSrc = $script->src;
  //load js, parse or whatever
}
```

From there you can grab the css or js source url and do what you want with it.

Comment: Looks promising.  Thanks for the start.  I will try it out and post my findings.

Comment: Good deal. Hope it helps. It's saved my butt a few too many times.